# How do I get the total sectors or size of a cd-rw with a closed file system on it

Tags: c++, com, cd-burning

How do I get the total sectors or size of a cd-rw with a closed file system on it in C++. With Microsoft com object IDiskFormat2Data::get_TotalSectorsOnMedia I can get the 'free' number of sectors on a cd-rw. But if the disk is a cd-rw with data on it and is closed this call will return zero. But I want to find out how much room there would be if I would erase the current data and write the new data to it. I have some other system calls that will give me the size of the file system on the cd, but I need a way of getting the unused or total sectors or bytes on the cd-rw. Thanks